# Spring Security JWT destroy token via Logout

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I will develop single page web application. But I don't have enough information about security for single-page applications.

I read this post which about JWT : https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

1) Is JWT enough to secure a single page app?

2) Generating JWT and using it with client app is clear but what about logout mechanism. For example in webapp if user clicks to "Logout" button what should happen. Which request should be send to server and what will happen at server.
As far as I know tokens are not storing in database in this tutorial: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/?

3) I think about generate whole security mechanism on JWT As far as I learned from this post : https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/ is it enough to protect my server and communicate with my web app?